# Why does my MVar freeze my code?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, client-server

I am trying to create a simple server using Haskell. When clients connect to the server, the server records their address. Every **n** microseconds the server sends out a broadcast.

Here is the server

```
data Server = Server {
  sSocket :: Socket,
  sPort :: Port,
  sClients :: MVar [ClientAddress]
  }
```

(Notice the MVar that allows the clients to be used from multiple threads.)

This is how a server is created

```
startServer port = withSocketsDo $ do
  socket  <- listenOn $ PortNumber $ fromIntegral port
  clients <- newEmptyMVar
  let server = Server socket port clients
  forkIO $ forever $ accept socket >>= forkIO . (handleClientRequest server)
  forever $ updateClients server 1000000
```

The server uses its thread and forks another. The forked thread handles any incoming client requests

```
handleClientRequest server client = do
  clients <- takeMVar $ sClients server
  putMVar (sClients server) (client : clients)
```

and the broadcast is sent using the `updateClients` function

```
updateClients server frequency = do
  putStrLn "1"
  clients <- (takeMVar $ sClients server)
  putStrLn "2"
  putStrLn $ show $ length clients
  threadDelay frequency
```

The problem I encounter is that "2" is never printed to the screen. I believe this is because the `takeMVar` line in `updateClients` is never finishing.

Why would this freeze?

Comment: You start with an empty MVar, so `takeMVar` blocks forever.  Try using `newMVar []` instead of `newEmptyMVar`.  Also, if you can use `withMVar` instead of `takeMVar/putMVar` that's usually preferable, because it leaves the MVar in a consistent state if an async exception arises.

Comment: Thanks, John - that worked perfectly. (I used withMVar and modifyMVar_ to replace both take and put). If you throw this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start with an empty MVar, so `takeMVar` blocks forever. Try using `newMVar []` instead of `newEmptyMVar`, possibly like this:

```
startServer port = withSocketsDo $ do
  socket  <- listenOn $ PortNumber $ fromIntegral port
  clients <- newMVar []
  let server = Server socket port clients
  forkIO $ forever $ accept socket >>= forkIO . (handleClientRequest server)
  forever $ updateClients server 1000000
```

Now, the MVar is always full, except when it's actually being modified by a client.

When you use an MVar to protect a critical section, it's helpful to think of what the normal state is; in this case it's a list of clients.  The only time the MVar should be empty is when a client is actually modifying the state, so if you can use `modifyMVar` and set up the initial state, your code should be deadlock-free.

Also, if you can use `withMVar` instead of `takeMVar/putMVar` you should do so, because it leaves the MVar in a consistent state if an async exception arises.